How to leave current branch
Imagine I am on branch foo, possibly with changes in my working directory. I want to enter detached head state while maintaining the current commit and any changes in the working directory.
The simple solution of git checkout HEAD doesn't work. Git seems to notice what HEAD is and keeps the current branch.

The best solution I have found so far is:
git checkout $(git rev-parse HEAD)

It works, but is quite a mouthful. Is there a simpler way to leave the current branch?

git checkout @^0 or git checkout --detach


I want to enter detached head state while maintaining the current commit and any changes in the working directory.

Detached head, afaik, by definition, is when HEAD, index and working tree match each other, and that is not the tip of the branch. If you want to preserve the index and/or working tree -
git reset [--soft] is a way to go:

git reset --soft - resets history to the specified commit, but keeps the index and working tree intact.
It is a good alternative for interactive rebase squashing - it preserves dates.

git reset [--mixed] (--mixed is a default option) - resets the history to specified commit, resets index matching that commit, but keeps working tree intact.
It can be used as some sort of bulk/file-targeted rollback mechanism. Kinda tedious alternative to git checkout <hash> <file> command.



The simple solution of git checkout HEAD doesn't work.

Checkout always makes HEAD, index and working tree match each other. That's why you can't.

while maintaining the current commit and any changes in the working directory.

Again, you cant. Every HEAD manipulation commands change the history, by definiton, because HEAD - is a movable pointer to a specific commit. Using checkout or reset, you always change that pointer.
UPDATE

possibly with changes in my working directory.

If you meant untracked changes, this is what checkout does by default - it is working-tree safe (see table at the bottom of the page).

This is either phrased wrong or is wrong.

Could you please elaborate? Do you mean detached head definition is wrong? - It came from experience.

“Detached head, afaik, by definition, is when HEAD, index and working tree match each other, and that is not the tip of the branch.” This is either ambiguous or wrong. HEAD can point to the same commit as some branch (but did you mean that they couldn’t? This is the ambiguous part). Detached head is when HEAD points at a commit directly and not a branch.

"Detached head is when HEAD points at a commit directly and not a branch" - yep, and branch always points to its tip, ie the latest commit. So, if HEAD doesn't point to tip - it is detached head. Essentially the same.

I can’t make sense that “HEAD, index and working tree match each other, and that is not the tip of the branch”. Index and working tree state is irrelevant to whether you are on detached head or not. They don’t have to be the same. index, working tree, and HEAD can be equal to whatever some branches are pointing at.

I agree with @Guildenstern. Your definition of detached head is incorrect. Suppose branch1 points to commit ID a1b2c3. If you checkout branch1 you are not detached. If you checkout a1b2c3 directly, you are detached. HEAD points to the same commit ID in both cases.

@TTT, yeah, agree, never did this, thanks for clarification.

Anyway, i don't get the fundamental difference in that particular case, it's some magic with refs for me.

@Ryan the fundamental difference is literally whether HEAD is pointing to a branch or to a commit ID. Test: git switch main, cat .git/HEAD, git switch --detach, cat .git/HEAD. That file called HEAD in the root of your .git folder will change. It's contents will be either a branch name or a hash.

@TTT, Nah, i believe git just is not smart enough here - conceptually, there are two possible strings being contained in .git/HEAD - either  or . Working normally, we either checkout to particular  that is NOT tip, or just to  that IS definitely points to the tip. So, conceptually i adhere to definition mentioned in the answer. Checking out explicitly to a  that is branch tip is somewhat non-trivial hack that tricks git itself.
